# magnificPopup always detect same video youtube

Tags: php, jquery, video, youtube, magnific-popup

hy guys I have problem in magnificPopup iframe video youtube & my problem is why magnificPopup always detect same video youtube when I click other video, I try like this but dosent work

```
        $(document).on('click', '.play__video__hole', function (e) {

         var ind = $(this).data('index');
       //different url video
        console.log($('.urlVideo_'+ind).val());
        //different url video
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.play__video__hole').magnificPopup({
            items: {
                src: $('.urlVideo_'+ind).val(),
                type: 'iframe',
                preloader: false,
            },
            closeBtnInside: true
        });

    });
```

Comment: Play the last video? js closure =)

Comment: hy @Eugene Smith thanks for your answer but I no I understand what do you mean